# How to Import Java Class from ViewController in Model Impl Class in Oracle adf?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using Jdeveloper 12 ... I have a custom Java Class in ViewController Project in oracle adf...
How can I access and use that class in the VO Impl class  in Model ??

Comment: You may not be able to do that because of circular dependencies. Try adding the "source" directory of Model, and include the folder of your common class in Model too.

Answer (score 2):

In the Model project go to Project Properties > Dependencies and then click the green + to Add.

Expand the View Controller Project and Select "Build Output". Rebuild the app and now you can import the packages from the View Controller Application Sources.

Comment: I know this but the default of adf project is in viewController Project  in the dependancies part we have our Model project but we can't have a circle of dependancies ... it means we can't have ViewController Project in Model Project dependancy while we have model in viewController  project Dependancies @Joe

Comment: why not create a separate view controller or model project to hold the shared code? Also, when posting questions it helps us who are trying to help you if you tell us what you have tried and did not work and why.

Comment: Since you're doing ADF development, you might find this free aggregation site I use when I teach ADF for Oracle useful: https://joestechland.com/oracle/adf-desktop/   And you should watch this advanced video on ADF Architecture : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toEuQvp73h8architecture: